# port 100 not running in node.js in localhost

Tags: node.js, sails.js, port, httpserver

I have created a http server in node.js with the following code, and trying to run it on port 100:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end("Howdy");
}).listen(100);

console.log("server running on port 100");
```

With this, the server does not start and I am getting the following error message on the linux console:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/badhai/Desktop/mainn.js:6:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

But if I lift a sails.js app on port 100, it runs successfully on port 100. However, the above code runs successfully on port 8081. I want to know if I need to make any changes in the server creation method or elsewhere so that it can be made to run successfully on port 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EACCES` part of the error message is the key here - it means you don't have access to that port. Ports < 1024 are system reserved. It's better to use ports in the range 1024-65535

Answer (score 1):

Most modern operating systems limit binding to reserved ports (less than 1024) to processes running as root (or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must bind to port 100, googling around will give you a bunch of ways to do it:

https://gist.github.com/firstdoit/6389682

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use ports > 1024. I'm using ports starting from 3000. But if you really want to start it on port 100 and you understand what you're doing then install `setcap` and just allow to bind ports <1024.

```
> sudo apt-get install setcap
> sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/node
```

NodeJS can be installed in other directory also, so better to check where it is and call above `setcap` command with your path.

```
> which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```